# Rails mountable engine assets wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

Try to write my own gem. Here it is - https://rubygems.org/gems/my_nagios

Now I test it in production mode, and have an issue with assets :(

I mount my engine to blank test app, run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and `rails s -e production`

Here is the sample of generated HTML code:

```
rails s -e production                                                                                                      
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000

*html part:*
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/my_nagios/application-b7081ae4e3f75191771e5bca0f372b0c689e263d4ba3f8764fed0d05e85c7cbc.css" />
<script src="/assets/my_nagios/application-1d5e57485e3c57578b072e17f6b54527f87022c41922cc479b1f83ea7ceed523.js"></script>
```

But by this path a have 404 error.

Is anyone have any idea why?

Comment: If I set config.assets.compile = true in my "test blank app environtment/production.rb" - it shows correctly all styles and images

Comment: rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

I, [2016-05-19T16:32:33.123255 #22240]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/.../my-app/public/assets/my_nagios/application-b7081ae4e3f75191771e5bca0f372b0c689e263d4ba3f8764fed0d05e85c7cbc.css
I, [2016-05-19T16:32:33.123453 #22240]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/...my_app//public/assets/my_nagios/application-b7081ae4e3f75191771e5bca0f372b0c689e263d4ba3f8764fed0d05e85c7cbc.css.gz